# How to compare the response time trend while running JMeter Scripts with Jenkins & Maven

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

While running jmeter test with maven & jenkins, previously used the Jenkins performance plugin for comparing responsetime over the buildwith trend.  Due to the XXE vulnerability on the plugin we have stopped using the same. Do we have any other jenkins plugin to compare the response time of the URLs \  transactions on the jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any other Jenkins plugins, you could consider [Merge Results plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) which can be used for building charts and allowing you to compare different test executions:

[image]

Merge Results plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)